# How to correctly pass an object related to a jQuery ListView line to the specific controller method?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a jQuery view that show a list of `Fix` object, this one:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b" data-split-icon="delete">
    @foreach (DataModel.Vulnerability.Fix item in Model.VulnerabilityFixes)
    {         
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Product", new { Title = item.Title })">
            <h2>@item.Title</h2>
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>FixName</th>
                    <th>Vendor</th>
                    <th>Version</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@MyHelper.decodeNull(item.Id)</td>
                    <td>@MyHelper.decodeNull(item.FixName)</td>
                    <td>@MyHelper.decodeNull(item.Vendor)</td>
                    <td>@MyHelper.decodeNull(item.Version)</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </a>
            <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteFix", "Editing", new { vulnId = Model.Id, currentFix = item })">Delete</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

As you can see, this list contains a button (a link) to delete the related fix, this one:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DeleteFix", "Editing", new { vulnId = Model.Id, currentFix = item })">Delete</a>
```

When this link is clicked is called the **DeleteFix()** method of the **EditingController** class that take 2 paramethers:

1. `vulnId` that is a `long` value.
2. The `Fix` object related to the clicked link line.

So this is my `DeleteFix()` method,

```
public ActionResult DeleteFix(long vulnId, DataModel.Vulnerability.Fix currentFix) 
{

    DataModel.Vulnerability.Fix model = new DataModel.Vulnerability.Fix();

    manager.openConnection();

    try
    {
        model = currentFix;
    }
    finally
    {
        manager.closeConnection();
    }

    return View(model);

}
```

The problem is that the when enter into the method the `vulnId` parameter is correctly set but the `currentFix` parameter is `null`.

What am I missing? What can I do to correctly pass the `Fix` object related to the line on which I pressed the delete button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass an "object" in a URL.  You can only pass text.  (Although you could serialize the object).  You probably want to pass the Id of the item.  Thus the link should look like:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DeleteFix", "Editing", new { vulnId = Model.Id, currentFix = item.Id })">Delete</a>
```

You action should be:

```
public ActionResult DeleteFix(long vulnId, int currentFix)
```

Then you can use the Id to delete the item.